# Node js (Express framework & MongoDb) passing a model to a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, function, express, parameters

I have been making a website and in it I found that I have been reusing the same code again and again for creating an entry in the database.

My Stack - Nodejs MongoDb & Express Framework

If I find a way to pass model and object to a function then the function would make an entry for me in the database then I can reuse the same function again and again. I am able to pass the object but unable to pass the model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with passing model to a function. Model itself is just an object so if you say that you are able to pass an object to a function, that means that you are able to pass model as well.

Following code works for me.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('your-database-URI');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

const customSave = (obj, model) => {
  const entry = new model(obj);

  entry.save();
};

customSave({ username: 'Sue' }, User);
```